# Exclude /ru/ in links

Tags: theming

I have site http://diamant-group.com/. It has two languages RU and EN, I want that it will monolingual, with Russian default language. I turn off EN language in Configuration, turn on RU as default, but problem is still exist http://diamant-group.com/ru/catalog. When I begin to research I have opened that many code for multilingual function was added inside theme template. When I turn off module Content translate i have error of function diamant_link_lang.

How to correct this code, that links do not consist /ru/ (for example site/ru/catalog/watches/mechanical/omega/ - > site/catalog/watches/mechanical/omega/), but language of the result pages must be Russian:

```
function diamant_link_lang($language, $path, $path_alt) {
    $path_lang = translation_path_get_translations($path_alt[0] . '/' . $path_alt[1], $language);
    file_put_contents(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/default/files/text.txt', 'path_lang: ' . print_r($path_lang, true) . "\n");
    if ($language == 'ru' && isset($path_lang['en']))
 {
        return 'en/' . drupal_get_path_alias($path_lang['en'], 'en');
    }
    if ($language == 'en' && isset($path_lang['ru'])) {
        return drupal_get_path_alias($path_lang['ru'], 'ru');
    }
    return $language == 'ru' ? 'en' : 'ru';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way the language is added to the url. For the Russian language (your default language), you can remove it completely from the url by setting the `path prefix` to empty value.

This can be done under `admin/config/regional/language/edit/ru`, set empty value on `Path prefix language code`.

Theoretically you don't need to have custom code the generate URL (with language checks), just let Drupal handle the url generation.

Comment: Mike, thank you for participation! we checked all files as result we had found that paths are implemented in code of the nodes! -  $bid = arg(1); 
        if ($bid == ''){
            print '<li class="active"><a href="/' . $language->language . '/brands">' . t('ALL') . '</a></li>';
        } else {
            print '<li><a href="/' . $language->language . '/brands">' . t('ALL') . '</a></li>';
        } //if'